# What is the best way to read a JSON structure entered through the command line?

Tags: java, json, command-line, inputstream

I need to read a JSON structure being entered through command line and stored in a variable. I want to know what is the best way to read a JSON structure that can contain empty lines such as:

```
{ "report":[
      {"enrollment": "rit123" },

      {"enrollment": "rit345" }
  ]
}
```

. In this case there exists one blank line between the two JSON objects inside the JSON array. If i use a while loop and a method like hasNextLine() it won't read everything since as soon as the empty line is encountered it can terminate the loop.

Constraints:
I don't know where the empty lines are located or how many there will be.

Comment: What's the use case behind this? You can also pass json as run arguments and access it as args[0]

Comment: @Smile the use case is for a hacker rank question scenario.

Answer (score 0):

With the information you have provided, the best way you could read the JSON format would be bracket matching.
After reading each line, count the number of opening and closing brackets.
And loop until opening bracket count is not equal to closing bracket count.

This way, even when there are multiple empty lines, your while loop won't be terminated.